# Square Summable functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Can somebody please help me understand the notion of square summable functions intuitively??
I have been self studying Hilbert Spaces and Fourier Transform for DSP. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is a Square summable sequences intuitively ?

Answer (score 6):

A square summable function $f$ is one where $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|^2 dx < \infty$.

Think about functions that violate this.  Any function that goes to infinity (e.g. $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$) is not square summable.  But even nicer functions violate this.  For example, any non-zero constant function (e.g. $f(x)=1$) is not square summable.

So square summable is a relatively strong condition.  Not only do functions need to go to zero in both directions, but they have to go to zero "quickly" enough to be square summable.

I hope this help.

Comment: The function $f$ defined by $f(x) = |x|^{-1/4}$ if $0 < |x| < 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise is unbounded near $0$ but is square summable.

Comment: "Square summable" is is just another way to say "square integrable", right?  Strictly speaking, shouldn't the former only be applied to sequences rather than functions?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-summable